# How can i use two different php-fpm pools depending on url

Tags: nginx, php, php-fpm

I would also like to use 2 php-fpm pools.

My directory structure looks like this:

```
/home/test/index.php
/home/test/contact.php
/home/test/stats.php
```

document root is:

```
root /home/test;
```

When I call the stats.php the pool with the fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9001; should be taken, but all other PHP's (index.php, contatct.php) should use the pool with the fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000; should be taken.

If I insert this location block every PHP uses the fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9001

```
location = /stats.php {
       include fastcgi_params;
       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name; 
       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9001;
}
```

No matter if I insert it before or after this block

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
}
```

Thanks

**Update 12.06.2020:**

i have the following in the /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:

```
map $request_uri $pool {
    "/stats.php" 127.0.0.1:9001;
    default 127.0.0.1:9000;
}
```

and in the /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:

```
location \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass $pool;     
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

nevertheless all PHP's only use the fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000

The tip with the map function comes from here:
[Nginx: How to use a different php-fpm pool depending on url](https://serverfault.com/questions/882063/nginx-how-to-use-a-different-php-fpm-pool-depending-on-url)

How must the map function looks like when i want to use stats.php with params? e.g.

```
stats.php?time=123456&id=1754852
```

It looks like it doesn't work like this

```
map $request_uri$is_args$args $pool {
    "/stats.php" 127.0.0.1:9001;
    default 127.0.0.1:9000;
}
```

Comment: Compare your map to the one given in the tip.

Comment: THX i found a mistake but it still doesn't work

Comment: Can you show what a request for stats.php looks like?   Does it contain parameters?

Comment: the stats.php request is /stats.php without any params

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A location with a regex needs "~" or "~*", as in

```
location ~ \.php$ {
  fastcgi_pass $pool;
}
```

For the map request to work when there are request parameters, one should use the $uri iso. the $request_uri.

```
map $uri $pool {
  "/stats.php" 127.0.0.1:9001;
  default 127.0.0.1:9000;
}
```

Alternative would be to use $request_uri and a regex iso. "/stats.php".

Comment: THX now it works without params and with params? See my edited question

Comment: regex is a red cloth for me, how should the regex looks like for the "/stats.php" 127.0.0.1:9001; ? Theoretically, all characters could appear in the params. map $uri $pool {....} doesn't work.

Comment: It should work, as did your "location = /stats.php".  There must be other directives in your configuration that cause problems.

Comment: I don't know why but now it works. I have deleted everything again and re-entered and now it works. Many thanks for the help.